# Arrays - Javascript - filter array of objects using input search

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to filter a list using react, but surprisingly, for such a common task, cannot find anything online to help me achieve this.

I have an array of users which I then want to filter through (starting off with name - I can work out filtering by age then). 
The array is in my redux store and looks like the below.

```
let users = [
  {
    name: 'Raul',
    age: 29
  },
  {
    name: 'Mario',
    age: 22
  }
];
```

My entire component looks like the below.

```
class Test extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            users: this.props.users

        };

        this.filterList = this.filterList.bind(this);

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

        this.setState({
            users: nextProps.users
        });

    }

    filterList(event) {

        let users = this.state.users;
        users = users.filter(function(user){
        //unsure what to do here
        });
        this.setState({users: users});
    }

  render(){

    const userList = this.state.users.map((user) => {
      return <li>{user.name} {user.age}</li>;
    });

    return(
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={this.filterList}/>
      <ul>
        { userList }
      </ul>
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: what is the filter criteria?

Comment: apologies @pablogq filter by name. well ideally both, but can start with name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to filter for `name` you can use `.filter` together with `.startsWith` or `.indexOf` to return true or false for a given user.

You've also set a new list of users on the onChange event, which results in an empty array sooner or later. Here I've used the `user` state that is only changed by the props, and a `filteredUsers` that is changed when a keystroke happened.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      users: this.props.users,
      filteredUsers: this.props.users,
      q: ''
    };

    this.filterList = this.filterList.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState(
      {
        users: nextProps.users,
        filteredUsers: nextProps.users
      },
      () => this.filterList()
    );
  }

  onChange(event) {
    const q = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    this.setState({ q }, () => this.filterList());
  }

  filterList() {
    let users = this.state.users;
    let q = this.state.q;

    users = users.filter(function(user) {
      return user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) != -1; // returns true or false
    });
    this.setState({ filteredUsers: users });
  }

  render() {
    const userList = this.state.filteredUsers.map(user => {
      return <li>{user.name} {user.age}</li>;
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
          value={this.state.q}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <ul>
          {userList}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const userList = [
  {
    name: 'Raul',
    age: 29
  },
  {
    name: 'Mario',
    age: 22
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(<Test users={userList} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: how would the index of look?

Comment: You can do an if statement there. If the result from `.indexOf(q)` is `-1`, return false. Else, return true. Or `user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) != -1` to do it in one line.

Comment: thanks! just one issue! the array of users keeps growing so when there are more users added they are not shown. do you know how i can get around this.?!

Comment: Updated my answer. You want to also update the `filteredUsers` state when the component receives new props. Also you might want to call `filterList` manually again depending on the behaviour you want.

Comment: this is what I had already tried, but this breaks the filter search as the whole array is shown again when a new user is added to the array. Know what I mean?

Comment: Yep like I mentioned, call `this.filterList` after the state transition happened. Updated my answer.

Comment: i get what you mean but it doesnt seem to work. I am getting this error  - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Comment: Sorry, couldn't test it. Try it with `let q = event ? event.target.value.toLowerCase() : '';` inside the `filterList` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138960/discussion-between-raul-rodriguez-and-fabian-schultz).

Answer (score 1):

You need one more `state` variable to store the search result, initialise that variable by same data, once user type anything store the filtered data in that, Try this:

```js
let users = [
  {
    name: 'Raul',
    age: 29
  },
  {
    name: 'Mario',
    age: 22
  }
];

class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            users: users,
            result: users,
        };

        this.filterList = this.filterList.bind(this);

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

        this.setState({
            users: nextProps.users,            
        });

    }

    filterList(event) {
        let value = event.target.value;
        let users = this.state.users, result=[];
        result = users.filter((user)=>{
            return user.name.toLowerCase().search(value) != -1;
        });
        this.setState({result});
    }

  render(){

    const userList = this.state.result.map((user) => {
      return <li>{user.name} {user.age}</li>;
    });

    return(<div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={this.filterList}/>
      <ul>
        {userList}
      </ul>
      </div>
    );

  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id='app'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let datas =[
  {   
      "id":1,
      "title":"Ucat",
      "handle":"mi"
  },
  {
      "id":2,
      "title":"Acat",
      "handle":"csk"
  },
  {
      "id":3,
      "title":"Vcat",
      "handle":"kkr"
  },
  {
      "id":4,
      "title":"Atar",
      "handle":"pkbs"
  }];
const [search, setSearch] =useState(datas);
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
var dm = e.target.value;
var str =dm.toString();
var debug = datas.filter(x=> x["title"].toLowerCase().includes(str));
setSearch(debug);};


<input type="text"  onChange={handleInputChange}/>
{search.map((item)=>(
    <div key={item.id}>
        <ul>
            <li>
            {item.handle} 
            <br/>
            {item.title}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
))};
```

Comment: When posting an answer please provide relevant explanation so the the person who asked can understand the solution better

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the list, you must have a criteria to filter against. For instance you have a variable `let filterAge = 18;`

In that case you can filter the userlist against that value using

```
let users = users.filter(function(user){
    //return all users older or equal to filterAge
    return user.age >= filterAge;        
});
```

Every result from the function that equals true, will be added to the `users` variable. A false return will leave it out. How you determine true / false is up to you. Hardcode it (not very useful), a simple equals statement (as above) or a function doing higher math. Your choice.

Comment: http://codepen.io/pjmtokyo/pen/ZGVjVV this one seems to do it on a case by case basis, without something as explicit as `if user is older than 18`

Comment: can u see where `search` is defined for this one?

Comment: Well, here he is specifing using a function to determine if the (lowercase) name has the given value (in lowercase), using the search function.

Comment: ah yeah, didnt know there was a js `search` method. feel free to update your answer and I can give u a green tick

Comment: He is using the default javascript string search function. See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp for more details. If that string contains the given value, it returns the place in the string where that value starts. If it's at the begin, the value returns 0. If it isn't in there, it returns -1. But overall he matches the search value against every item in the filter function.

Comment: Made it a bit more specific on how the filter works. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It always worked well for me that way.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([{name: 'Kondo'}, {name: 'Gintoki'}])

const handleFilterFilesTable = () => {
    return data
      .filter((element) => {
        if (searchText !== "") {
          return element?.name?.toLowerCase()?.includes(searchText?.toLowerCase())
        }

        return element
      })
  }

// ...
return (
 //...
 <Table data={handleFilterFilesTable()} />
)
```

That way I can apply multiple filters working together simply by extending the **filter** method like this

```js
// ...
return data.filter().filter().filter()//...
// ...
```